node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:453 throw err;
When I run
npm start
in the frontend server, in VSCode editor I get the following error:-
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:453
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\UserA\OneDrive\Desktop\sweet_sensations\frontend\node_modules\fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:445:19)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:716:18)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1131:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:986:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\UserA\OneDrive\Desktop\sweet_sensations\frontend\node_modules\fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin\lib\formatter\CodeFrameFormatter.js:7:36)        
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1358:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1416:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1208:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\UserA\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\sweet_sensations\\frontend\\node_modules\\fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin\\node_modules\\fs-extra\\package.json',
  requestPath: 'fs-extra'
}

I also installed cjs-loader but nothing changed.
